# How to activate a cell without going to the cell's page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this code. It run ok, but in the middle it goes to the second page and comes back. I don't want to see that process. I think is because the code "Activate" but I'm not sure.

I don't want to see that process.

```
function cargacierredecaja() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const hojadeentrada=ss.getSheetByName('Carga Cierre de caja');
  const hojadesalida=ss.getSheetByName('BASE DE DATOS');
  const rangocargadatos=hojadeentrada.getRange('A5:Q21').getValues();
  var balanza=hojadeentrada.getRange('F5').getValue();
  var efectivo=hojadeentrada.getRange('H5').getValue();
  var posnet=hojadeentrada.getRange('J5').getValue();
  var anulados=hojadeentrada.getRange('L5').getValue();
  var transferencias=hojadeentrada.getRange('K5').getValue();
  var iniciocaja=hojadeentrada.getRange('G5').getValue();
  var proxcaja=hojadeentrada.getRange('I5').getValue();
  var egresosdeldia=hojadeentrada.getRange('M5:M21').getValues().reduce(function (a, b) { return a[0] + b[0]});
  var ingresonet=(parseInt(efectivo)+parseInt(posnet)+parseInt(transferencias)+parseInt(egresosdeldia)-parseInt(proxcaja)+iniciocaja);
  var ultimafecha=hojadeentrada.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var resto=parseInt(ingresonet)+parseInt(anulados)-balanza;
  var ultimajornada=hojadeentrada.getRange('E5').getValue();

 
  hojadesalida.getRange('AB2').activate();
  hojadesalida.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  hojadesalida.getCurrentCell().offset(1, -12, 17,17).setValues(rangocargadatos);
  hojadesalida.getCurrentCell().offset(1,-13).activate().setValue(ingresonet);
  hojadesalida.getCurrentCell().offset(0,-1).activate().setValue(resto);
  hojadeentrada.getRange('D5:Q21').clearContent();
  hojadeentrada.getRange('B5').clearContent();
  hojadeentrada.getRange('F3').setValue(ultimafecha);
  hojadeentrada.getRange('H3').setValue(ultimajornada);
  hojadeentrada.getRange('A5').activate();
  hojadeentrada.getRange('F5:M5').setValue(0);
  hojadeentrada.getRange('P5').setValue(0);
  
}
```

Comment: You do don't have activate a cell too write or read from it.  That's a remnant of learning how too write scripts by editing recorded macros.  Personally, I hate that type of code.  Don't even like to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like it was created inside Sheets by recording a macro which mimmicks what the user did when the macro was recorded, cell moves and all.

To select a cell you can modify your code like this:

```
hojadesalida.getRange('AB2').activate();
```

becomes

```
hojadesalida.getRange('AB2')
```

If you have to get values from cells on multiple sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2 you could rely on this pattern:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // to refer to this Google Sheet
var configSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // to create a variable pointing to Sheet1
var workSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // to create a variable pointing to Sheet2
var desiredValue = configSheet.getRange('AB2').getValue(); // to capture the value from Sheet1, cell AB2
```

Google's docs are really quite good for apps script.  This link should get you started: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet